# Count Lines at a ftp .txt php

Tags: php, count

I have a quesion: How to count lines at a file over ftp?

Like: I have a file generated by C# shared by ftp. How to count the lines at php at my webserver?

Thanks, Jonathan

Comment: Is the file directly accessible? if so, you can just open the file and count the lines. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: No, it isnt. The C# Project is at my own pc and the webserver i hire.

Comment: What I mean is: where is the .txt saved? where is your webserver?

Comment: Web server: One pc
C#: Other pc

Comment: Are the PCs on the same network? Please give us more informations about that. You **MUST** be able to open the file, the big problem here is not opening the file and counting the lines (which can be easily done using fopen and fgets), but it is rather being able to open it, due to the fact that it NEEDS to be stored in a place where both machines can access it, either locally either on the internet.

Comment: Is there a way to download it and then open?
C# I host it in my home.
WebServer. I host from a webhosting. So elsewere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can access the file then can do this:

```
$file="yourfile.txt";
$count = 0;
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($fp)){
  $line = fgets($fp);
  $count++;
}

fclose($fp);

echo $count;
```

you can use **count()** also :

```
$count = count( file( $file));
```

but if the file is big you should avoid using this.